# SimpleDateFormat localized month names

Tags: java, localization, simpledateformat

I have searched throughout the site but I think I have a slightly different issue and could really do with some help before I either have heart failure or burn the computer.

I dynamically generate a list of month names (in the form June 2011, July 2011) and obviously I want this to be locale sensitive: hence I use the simple date format object as follows:

```
//the actual locale name is dependent on UI selection
Locale localeObject=new Locale("pl"); 
// intended to return full month name - in local language.
DateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy",localeObject);
//this bit just sets up a calendar (used for other bits but here to illustrate the issue
String systemTimeZoneName = "GMT";
TimeZone systemTimeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone(systemTimeZoneName);
Calendar mCal = new GregorianCalendar(systemTimeZone); //"gmt" time
mCal.getTime(); //current date and time
```

but if I do this:

```
String value=dtFormat.format(mCal.getTime());
```

this "should" return the localized version of the month name.  In polish the word "September" is "Wrzesień" -- note the accent on the n.  However all I get back is "Wrzesie?"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to all - I accept now that it's a presentation issue - but how can I "read" the result from dtFormat safely - I added some comments below ref using getBytes etc. - this worked in other situations, I just can't seem to get access to the string result without messing it up

-- FINAL Edit; for anyone that comes accross this issue

The answer was on BalusC's blog : http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#DevelopmentEnvironment

Basically the DTformat object was returning UTF-8 and was being automatically transformed back to the system default character set when I read it into a string

so this code worked for me

```
new String(dtFormat.format(mCal.getTime()).getBytes("UTF-8"),"ISO-8859-1");
```

thank you very much for the assistance

Comment: Works fine here. Your problem is in the presentation. Please edit your question to include more detail about this. How exactly are you presenting it? What UI technology are you using?

Comment: k, well at the moment I'm doing a simple "System.out.println" however in UI (all of which is displaying polish characters fine) I'm using JSP with this at top of page <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  and lang="pl" in the form element (select list) that is displaying the resulting string.

Comment: as you can probably tell I am lowest of low in terms of Java knowledge; however I have all menus etc. on the app working perfectly switching between different languages (handcoded so no underlying framework)

Comment: another thought - sorry keep pressing enter when I finish a line... I tried using "new String(dtFormat.format(mCal.getTime()).getBytes("UTF-8")) & "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: So, you're only encountering the problem in stdout (there where `System.out.println()` ends up in) and not in generated HTML output of the JSP in the browser? Where is the stdout connected to? Command prompt console? IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans) console? Log file?

Comment: sorry BalusC, I wasn't clear about that, I AM outputting to html as well as to the default system console (running JBOSS here); all my other HTML rendering works in multiple languages, precisely what I do with the result is this: I add it to an array of strings which is then returned to the UI page as an arrayList - iterating through these I simply output the result in an <option></option> list - please bear with me on this, all my other localized strings come from a DB table - and all work fine on system.out and rendering

Comment: stdout goes tot he default command prompt where I started JBOSS (is that the right term?)

Comment: @user977184: Ignore the system console; concentrate on the JSP. You definitely should *not* be explicitly trying to mess with the encoding as you've shown with your `getBytes` call. It should just work fine, unless your JSP declares one encoding in the page but the header uses a different one. Look in Wireshark at what's *actually coming across the wire*, in terms of bytes, headers, and page metadata tags.

Comment: k, wireshark reports content type is UTF-8 as expected, I have this is in the html code <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">; also all menus and other localized strings are rendering correctly

Comment: This cannot be fixed. In theory, you need to configure the command prompt to use UTF-8 code page and configure a command prompt font which supports those characters. But there is no such font for Windows. However, for example writing the string to file using for example `new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")` and then viewing it in UTF-8 capable editor should show the right chars. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#DevelopmentEnvironment After all, just accept Jon's answer. While it is not specific enough, he despreately needs 15 more points.

Comment: :) me thinks I'm caught in some politics here; -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `SimpleDateFormat` - you're just doing the wrong thing with the result.

You haven't told us what you're doing with the string afterwards - how you're displaying it in the UI - but *that's* the problem. You can see that it's fetching a localized string; it's only the display of the accented character which is causing a problem. You would see exactly the same thing if you had a string constant in there containing the same accented character.

I suggest you check all the encodings used throughout your app if it's a web app, or check the font you're displaying the string in if it's a console or Swing app.

If you examine the string in the debugger I'm sure you'll see it's got exactly the right characters - it's just how they're getting to the user which is the problem.

Comment: Didn't this comment fit in a real comment to the question?

Comment: @BalusC: No, it wouldn't have done (208 characters over) - and I believe it will actually provide an answer the OP's problem. I've suggested how they should proceed to get past the problem, so I think it's reasonable to count it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, `dtFormat.format(mCal.getTime())` returns

> październik 2011

`new SimpleDateFormat(0,0,localeObject).format(mCal.getTime())` returns:

> poniedziałek, 3 październik 2011 14:26:53 EDT